# Getting items on click from a custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom ListView with 4 textviews inside. The values in the ListView is populated from the database.

This is how it looks like:

[image]

And this is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/budgetCategoryLV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Category"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expenseBudgetLV"
            android:layout_width="14dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Expense Budget"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/budgetSpentLV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Spent"
            android:textSize="13sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalBalanceLV"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Total Balance"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </LinearLayout>    </LinearLayout>
```

What I want to do is to click on an item in the ListView, and display it in a Toast Message.

This is a snippet of what I did so far, but it does not work for me:

```
 currentBudgetListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String value = currentBudgetListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); //this does not work
                        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.budgetCategoryLV); // this gives the default value of the textview
                        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expenseBudgetLV);
                        TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.budgetSpentLV);
                        TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalBalanceLV);
                        String text1 = tv1.getText().toString();
                        String text2 = tv2.getText().toString();
                        String text3 = tv3.getText().toString();
                        String text4 = tv4.getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(ExpensesBreakdownActivity.this, text1 + " " + text2 + " "  + text3 + " " + text4 + " " + value , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: You're trying to initialize the `TextViews` without passing the rootView in which they're declared. So, change every `TextView's` declaration from `(TextView) findViewById(` to `(TextView) view.findViewById(`. This view is what's been passed to you as an argument in the `onItemClick()`. This view is the view of any item which gets clicked. You can't access the `TextViews` of a list's item without the the root View. Same logic applies in a Fragment where you've to use the rootView to access the elements. Apart from this, You should use a view Model to access the items easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
currentBudgetListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                           final CurrentBudgetList user = (CurrentBudgetList)parent.getAdapter().getItem(position).getName();

                    Toast.makeText(ExpensesBreakdownActivity.this, ""+name , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                });
```

Comment: It gives me an id of the position but it does not give me the values of the position

Comment: try this if you have created a model then set the getter method to get the value of that model. just like getName();